# Why are there no power JFETs?

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, jfet

After doing a search on mouser, I found only 4 JFETs rated for more than 1A drain-source current, compared to almost 3,000 BJT and 11,000 MOSFETs. Is this because there is less of a market for a high current/high power JFET than MOSFET/BJT, or is there some physical limitation making it difficult to manufacture a high current JFET?

Comment: Because MOSFETs are somewhat easier to manufacture. They also work in both depletion and enhancement modes while JFETs can only work in depletion mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To control an N channel JFET you need to take the gate negative with respect to the source and this is useful in a lot of signal applications but not very convenient in power applications: -

[image]

Picture taken from [here](https://www.electrical4u.com/n-channel-jfet-and-p-channel-jfet/).

So with gate-source at 0 volts you get full conduction and, with gate going negative with respect to the source you control the drain current.

Nobody really likes to do that in power applications because it means having a negative power rail and this is inconvenient. However, there are a few power MOSFETs with this type of characteristic - look up depletion mode MOSFETs. These would be preferred to JFETs in power applications hence why bother designing a power JFET?

Comment: Not to mention the really annoying power case where the high voltage is present but the control power isn't... A six switch shoot-through at 540Vdc is noisy, messy and results in alot of explaining

Answer (score 2):

When I worked for National in the early 70's we produced samples of an N-channel  power JFET. As I remember, these were sections of a standard 2N3819 wafer with an interconnecting layer, and had something like 25 devices in parallel mounted in a TO-3 package. The intended market was principally HiFi manufacturers, but the lack of a complementary P-channel device was a drawback, and Marketing abandoned the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are are power JFETs, and quite powerful ones. Is 411W 650Vds 85A Id enough?
The UJ3N065025K3S https://unitedsic.com/group/sic-jfets/ this is a modern SiC jFET used in power suppliers and EVs there are also 1700Vds versions.

To control them (turn OFF because it is ON without gate voltage) you need to have about -15 Vgs. it is not dificult to get negative voltages from mains power even without a transformer by means of a capacitive voltage divider and a couple of diodes.